# I cannot run my code in IntelliJ. Instead of printing my code it prints "Hello World!"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is my first time using IntelliJ and I am learning to code Java. When I am pressing the button "run", my program does not print "I love pizza!" instead it prints "Hello World!". Why is this and how  can I fix it?

I have tried to run my code multiple times and I have added "application" as run configurations.

[image]

Comment: Please post code, not a picture of code.  No-one can run a picture.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I copy paste my code as a comment here?

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74379199/edit) your question. Most probably you are either running different main method or running the old code.

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my question. The follow up question becomes how do I check my main method so that the correct code is running?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new class in the /src directory
The hierachy would then be /YourProjectName/src/yourJavaClass

kind regards!